# For Loop and Pandas - setting attribute from list or variable

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I've got a Pandas dataframe with a lot of columns.  Inside a FOR loop I'm selecting a different subset of these fields each time through.

```
myList = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
for column in myList:
    df2 = df[['Day', column]]
    value = df2.column.min()
    value2 = df2.ix[df2.column.idxmin()]
```

For value, I get the error: "Dataframe has no attribute 'column'", so I've obviously got a syntax error.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sample Dataframes by request:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Monday', 4936.00, 5036.00, 130.18, 140.18, 40.67, 41.67, 166.96, 
    168.96, 145.87, 145.87],
    ['Tuesday', 5258.82, 5358.82, 141.99, 146.99, 41.00, 43.00, 169.70, 
    172.70, 155.00, 165.00]])

df2 = pd.Dataframe([
    ['Monday', 4936.00],
    ['Tuesday', 5258.82]])
```

In each iteration of the loop, the numbers in df2 move one place to the right.

Comment: what is `df` and `df2` provide sample of that dataframes?

Comment: What is the expected output? Besides that, your dfs have no headers?

Comment: Next time read this before posting ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass column like so:

```
for c in myList:
    df2 = df[['Day','{}'.format(c)]]
    value = df2['{}'.format(c)].min()
    value2 = df2.ix[df2['{}'.format(c)].idxmin()]
```

Edit: Note since `ix` is [deprecated](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), replace it with `iloc` instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: .ix is deprecated, use .loc here